# Narakasura story through various Vishnu avatars

Tags: krishna, naraka

Narakasura is the son of Vishnu (varaha avatar) and Bhoodevi.  He is mentioned only in Krishna avatar. So what happens in between? Was he quietly ruling all through the other avatars of Vishnu? Does he find mention elsewhere?